Pandas iterating over columns / map /applymap / stack/unstack function
i have got a Dataframe similiar to this one:
d={"PERSNR":["1111","22222","3333"],"KST":["1234","2345","34556"],"HQUALI1":["x","x",""],"HQUALI2":["x","",""],"HQUALI3":["","x","y"],
        "ZQUALI1":["x","x",""],"ZQUALI2":["","x",""],"ZQUALI3":["","x","x"]}
df2=pd.DataFrame(d)


mapping={"HQUALI1":"AQ06","HQUALI2":"AQ07","HQUALI3":"AQ08","ZQUALI1":"ZF15","ZQUALI2":"ZF13","ZQUALI3":"ZF49"}

Just that it has 150 Columns - i need to do following operations:
1.) How can i map my header without loosing headernames without matches?
for example:


i would want to keep "PERSNR" and "KST"
2.) i need to melt my Dataframe into following format where "HQUALI" and "ZQUALI" are aggregated in each possible combination where i have an entry.
PERSNR KST    HQUALI  ZQUALI
1111   1234    AQ06    ZF15 
1111   1234    AQ07    ZF45

i figured the rest out myself so far..
thanks for your help in advance

It looks like you have many questions, the "biggest problem" (according to you) had little to no explanation. Please rewrite your question, focus on one problem and clearly explain what is expected (input + exact expected output).

df2.rename(columns=mapping)?
